# Extract part of name with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract the part of names (everything after the last "_"):

```
BL_BU_TS_UI_UX -> UX
BL_BU_TS_AZ_Mobile -> Mobile
BL_BU_TS_UI_Projects -> Projects
```

Im using the following code:
SUBSTRING([BL_or_CL_Sponsor], CHARINDEX('_', [BL_or_CL_Sponsor], 1), 30) and it returns the following data:

```
_UI_UX
_AZ_Mobile
_UI_Projects
```

I was thinking to use REVERSE, but it says `error converting nvarchar to int`. Could you please help me?

Thanks, BR.

Comment: Please tag your Question with your RDBMS, as different databases have different functionality.

Comment: @Scratte SQL Server is the only RDBMS which has a `CHARINDEX` function to my knowledge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but the lack of tag means it doesn't come up on searches :) Snowflake apparently have it too, if that counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most performant option, but you could use a reverse trick here:

```
SELECT
    BL_or_CL_Sponsor,
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(BL_or_CL_Sponsor),
            CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(BL_or_CL_Sponsor)) - 1)) AS prefix
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

To see how this trick work, consider the breakdown of steps for the input `BL_BU_TS_UI_UX`:

```
BL_BU_TS_UI_UX
XU_IU_ST_UB_LB      (reverse string)
XU                  (take left until reaching, but including, first underscore)
UX                  (reverse this substring to obtain the prefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, s.value
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) s.value
      from string_split(t.BL_or_CL_Sponsor, '_') s
      where right(t.BL_or_CL_Sponsor, len(s.value)) = s.value
     ) s;
```

I don't know if this is faster than Tim's answer.  It just seems less error-prone.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e721857b9ce461f0d5806b262526d14) is a db<>fiddle.